# ranking of data based on multiple columns in mysql with using rank function

Tags: mysql, ranking

i am very new to mysql and tried to rank top records based on two fields

sharing you the current script and output along with the desired output

Current Script :

```
select u_rank, c_rank,u_name,c_name, 
        @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
from ( 
        SELECT u_rank, c_rank,u_name,c_name 
        from abc
    ) a, 
     (
        select @curRank := 0
    ) r 
order by c_rank,u_rank
```

Current OutpuT

[image]

MY DESIRED OUTPUT IS

[image]

Please help

Comment: It would be better if your desired and current output were text instead of images. We could then use the data for a mock up.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: On what basis you desired output is decided.

Answer (score 0):

If I am decifering your question correctly, you are wanting to rank the c_ranks ascending or each u_name and then order by that rank then the u_rank. After that you need to get a rank for all records in that order. I'm not sure that the way I just worded that made any sense... but the following should get that result for you:

```
SET @rank1 = 0;
SET @rank2 = 0;
SET @u_name = '';

SELECT u_rank, c_rank, u_name, c_name, @rank2 := @rank2 + 1 AS rank
FROM (
      SELECT u_rank, 
             c_rank, 
             c_name, 
             @rank1 := (@rank1 + 1 - IF(@u_name = u_name, 0, @rank1)) AS rank1, 
             @u_name := u_name AS u_name 
      FROM abc 
      ORDER BY u_name, c_rank
) foo
ORDER BY rank1, u_rank;
```

Comment: Glad to help! Remember it is customary on Stack Overflow to mark an accepted answer with the big green checkmark.